# Drag and drop in C for Windows and Linux

Tags: c, drag-and-drop

I'd like to implement Drag 'n Drop of files into my C-program which runs on Windows and Linux. On the web I only found solutions for Windows.

Somewhere I read that SDL provides methods for drag and drop, but I found no documentation about it at all, so I'm quite lost there.
If you could provide me with any directions or ideas, I'd be very grateful.

EDIT: Thank you for your responses. To be honest, the program uses a very unknown GUI library called agar (libagar.org). The codebase is quite big, so porting to another library will take a while. I am looking for an intermediate solution before porting.
Oh and the whole thing is programmed in C, so C++-only solutions don't work for me.

Comment: I guess you're talking GUI application here? If so, what are you using for the UI?

Comment: Drag & drop isn't necessarily a function of the C language; it's a function of whatever user interface toolkit/library/framework you're using. This can be WinAPI (on Windows) or X11 (on Unix), or something cross-platform like GTK. You probably don't want to do drag & drop using SDL, though.

Comment: I would suggest using QT or GTK.

Comment: Karoly: Qt is not available for C, as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to be C, or would C++ also be an option? If it could be, having mostly experience with Qt myself, I can recommend it as a GUI framework in general. It's cross platform, so will be of use on both Windows and Linux. What's more, it has fairly easy to use support for Drag & Drop behavior as described [in its documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/dnd.html). I would suggest it's worth a look.